# how to check MS Word paragraph line spacing using vba script

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph, line-spacing

how to check MS Word paragraph line spacing using vba script.
here is code where line spacing are change in paragraph(1).
we add paragraph(1) line space 2.
now how can we get it if we give same paragraph(1) and its gives us 2.

Comment: Can you share the code you have right now?

Comment: Paragraph formatting should be managed by applying a suitably-defined paragraph Style, not by overriding the format of whatever paragraph Style just happens to be where you're working.

Comment: `Sub asd()
   Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
   With myRange.ParagraphFormat
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceMultiple
    .LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1.5)
 End With
End Sub`  This Code only add (1.5) spacing in paragraph(1). Now i need a code that take paragraph(1) and gives me its line spacing. for example in this case it gives 1.5.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/how-to-check-ms-word-paragraph-line-spacing-using-vba-script.2350387/
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

To check line spacing: `Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing`

Te increase line spacing `Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = .LineSpacing + 1`

Te decrease line spacing `Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = .LineSpacing - 1`

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Record a macro where you change the line setting and then look at the result you get.

If there is any keyword you don't understand put the cursor on it and press F1, this will bring up the MS Help page for that keyword.

To record a macro you need to have the Developer Tab enabled.